# Is postcss-loader necessary for transpiling sass to css via webpack?

Tags: css, sass, node-sass, sass-loader, postcss-loader

I am currently learning sass/scss and I'm trying to set up a webpack configuration for a practice project. So I looked up the tools and technology I'd need, some resources suggested I use "node sass, sass-loader and css-loader"(the webpack documentation) while another suggested post-CSS instead of css-loader. I'd like to know the difference.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

No, you don't need `postcss-loader` in webpack to use SASS. `sass-loader` would alone do the work. Although, `node-sass` is required to be installed.

---

**What is PostCSS?**

> PostCSS is a tool for transforming CSS with JS plugins. These plugins can support variables and mixins, transpile future CSS syntax, inline images, and more.

Ref: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/postcss-deep-dive-what-you-need-to-know--cms-24535

`Autoprefixer` is one of the highly recommended plugin to use.

**What is SASS?**

SASS is a CSS preprocessor. Learn more here https://sass-lang.com/guide. `sass-loader` is webpack loader which does the same thing for you with the webpack tooling.

**What does node-sass do?**

> Node-sass is a library that provides binding for Node.js to LibSass, the C version of the popular stylesheet preprocessor, Sass.

It is not any alternative to `sass-loader`. `node-sass` is in `peerDependencies` of `sass-loader` so you'll need it to use `sass-loader`.

Ref: https://github.com/sass/node-sass

**Can you use both sass-loader and postcss-loader?**

Yes! And I would recommend you do use it together. In-fact, if you eject a Create React App project, in the webpack config you can find both `sass-loader` and `postcss-loader` used.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required but I do highly recommend the autoprefixer plugin. The loaders allow you to import the specified file types.

```
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'll look it up. Thanks